# What's this mini-cupola-looking object in this photo from the ISS?

Tags: iss, identify-this-object, photography

(I went through this exercise for my own benefit, so I figured I'd post it)

Recently stay-extended astronaut [Christina Hammock Koch](https://www.nasa.gov/astronauts/biographies/christina-hammock-koch/biography) posted this image to Facebook today and the object indicated by the red arrow caught my eye. It looked almost like a little version of the cupola, what is it?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using DOUG visualization software from NASA (available free [here](https://software.nasa.gov/software/MSC-23586-1), restrictions may apply) I looked out the Cupola windows until I found this view from Window 5.

[image]

Then flying outside I can see that the object is not, in fact, a cupola, but an external spare mounted on the Russian MRM-1 module.

[image]

In fact, it's a maybe-to-be-used-later-but-probably-never radiator for the long-delayed Russian [MPLM](https://spacenews.com/long-delayed-russian-module-for-iss-facing-more-problems/) module.

It was brought up by Shuttle mission STS-132 as seen in this cropped version of NASA Photo [iss023e044667](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/shuttle/sts-132/hires/iss023e044667.jpg).

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for that DOUG software link! Cool stuff :).

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn apparently there's a newer version called EDGE, but I have not used it.  https://software.nasa.gov/software/MSC-24663-1